# Simple Scrolling with jQuery

Tags: jquery, scroll

I have an AJAX navigation and I would like to scroll the page to the main title when the user clicks a link.

Let's suppose that the title has a #sampleid: I would like to do something like scrollTo #sampleid.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I normally solve problem with this [jQuery.ScrollTo](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/)

```
$.scrollTo( '#sampledid', 800, {easing:'elasout'} );
```